# How to clear data in ZF2 form collection?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have a ZF2 form with form collection element. The name of collection element is "roles". If I do:

```
$form->setData(array('roles' => array('admin', 'moderator')));
```

And then I do:

```
$form->setData(array('roles' => array())); // it does not work
```

Then if we do:

```
$form->get('roles')->getCount(); // 2
```

There will be still 2 elements. I need to clear elements from this collection.

It is very important for me because I use doctrine 2. So I should bind non-empty entity before I set data to the form. For instance:

```
$form->bind($entity); // $entity->roles is not empty
$form->setData($someData); // $someData['roles'] is empty array
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $form->get('roles')->getCount(); // 2(!) it is not empty!
    saveToDb($entity);
}
return $form;
```

Comment: Please show where to attach the 'roles' collection element to the form; there should be an option 'count' which is the initial collection count.

Comment: when I create collection I don't set count. By default count==1. When I do #form->bind($entity) $entity has two roles, that is why count==2. When I do $form->setData(['roles' => []]) roles collection count still equals two. This is a problem. If u will look at Collection::populateValues() method you will see that it does nothing if data is empty

Comment: Why not unset the roles property on the entity?